# Any way to use inner macro in exported macro without need to export the inner macro?

Tags: rust, macros

I've a declarative macro `macro_exported` exported with `#[macro_export]` to root.

In another module there is a 2nd, but internal macro `macro_intern`.
This is used/called via `#[macro_use]` in `macro_exported`.

But there seems to be no way to `pub use ...macro_inter;`: *`macro_intern` is only public within the crate, and cannot be re-exported outside*.
Is there any possibility without `#[macro_export] macro_intern` to root?

Why Rust doesn't expand the inner, not exported macros during compilation and provide an exported macro with all inner macro-calls expanded?

And a macro is no function. So it is no duplicate with using private functions in macros.

Comment: Closed with a fully unrelated answer. Are you joking!

Comment: Q: can you use private items like macros or functions in a public macro without exporting them A: no, best you can do is `#[doc(hidden)]` them. I don't really see how that's not related. Sure the item in question is a different one, but the answer is still the same, you can't use unexported items.

Comment: @cafce25 There is no answer to my 2nd last sentence (question)... why rust doesn't support it?!